# SQL Server MERGE: "when not matched by source"

Tags: sql-server, merge

I have more than a million rows in staging table. Every month staging table gets rows and after inserting into master table, those rows in staging are deleted.

There is another table called `allchanges` that keeps track of all updates made to the master table (say month1-address change,month2- phone change so all changes has 2 records) whereas master only has one updated record.

I used `MERGE` with `when matched`, `when not matched by target` and `when not matched by source`.

```
WITH  NewAndChanged
AS    (SELECT   TOP 2 stg.[EmpName],
                       stg.[EmpNumber],

       FROM     staging AS stg
       ORDER BY stg.[EmpNumber]
       EXCEPT
       SELECT   TOP 2 mas.[EmpName],
                       mas.[EmpNumber],

       FROM    [Master] AS mas
       ORDER BY mas.EmpNumber)
MERGE INTO [Master]
 AS Target
USING NewAndChanged AS Source ON Target.EmpNumber = Source.EmpNumber
WHEN MATCHED AND (COALESCE (Target.EmpName, '') <> COALESCE (Source.EmpName, '')
                  ) THEN UPDATE 
    SET Target.EmpName           = Source.EmpName,


WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ([EmpName], [EmpNumber])

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND Target.Active = 1 THEN UPDATE 
    SET Active = 0
    output $action as act;
```

Since I am selecting only 2 rows at a time, `when not matched by source` sets active to zero for the first 2 rows in the 2nd iteration. How can I overcome this??

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question.  What happens in the first iteration?

Comment: In the 1st iteration, since there are no records in master it goes to WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET and inserts. Second iteration, it is fetching next top 2 records which is WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE. This will not happen if I do not use "TOP (n)" records.